# How to use a single map container to put multiple type of Value objects

Tags: java, generics, collections

For example.

I have multiple classes as: Inventory , Product , Sales etc.

Now my requirement is to put all above types in a single map container. I  don't want to create multiple maps for putting above each object values.

Comment: something like this `Map<(your key class goes here), Object>` ?

Comment: Why do you want to use a `Map`. What will be the type of the key and the value?

Comment: Looks like you want to implement [Flyweight Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

If all your classes can implement the same interface, then you can store them all in the same container. Otherwise you would have to use Object...

More generally - why do you not want to use multiple maps?

Answer (score 1):

Set the value type as `Object`:

```
Map</*key goes here*/, Object> myMap = new Map</*key goes here*/, Object>();
```

Or, if `Inventory`, `Product`, `Sales`, and whatever else is going into the map share a superclass or implement the same interface, then set the value type as that:

```
Map</*key goes here*/, Superclass> myMap = new Map</*key goes here*/, Superclass>();
```